SQL Server JSON Queries
SQL query to check if a key exists and its value is null in JSON column
Extending this question, if I want to query for multiple keys, it works fine for me with both AND and OR in a SQL Server 2022 version:
SELECT *
FROM Logs
WHERE
    JSON_PATH_EXISTS(Parameters, '$.Name') = 1 AND
    JSON_PATH_EXISTS(Parameters, '$.Guid') = 1 AND
    (JSON_VALUE([Parameters], '$.Name') = 'Test') AND /* here testing both AND and OR */
    (JSON_VALUE([Parameters], '$.Guid') = '37aaecc3-e2f9-4b39-afcf-ba720c4e500a');

However, if I try to adjust SQL Server 2016+ example, it does wrong with AND:
SELECT * 
FROM [Logs] t
WHERE EXISTS (  
   SELECT 1
   FROM OPENJSON(t.[Parameters])
   WHERE ([key] = 'Name' AND [value] = 'Test') AND /* _here is problem_ */
   ([key] = 'Guid' AND [value] = '37aaecc3-e2f9-4b39-afcf-ba720c4e500a')
)

If I place OR in a problematic place, it queries fine - if both pairs do not match, nothing returns, if one or both statements match - row is returned correctly.
However, if I do AND query, if both pairs match, nothing is returned still. How do I fix second query so it works?

A possible option is WHERE EXISTS(... [key] = 'Name' AND [value] = 'Test' ...) AND EXISTS (... [key] = 'Guid' AND [value] = '37aaecc3-e2f9-4b39-afcf-ba720c4e500a' ...)?

@Zhorov true, this works! Can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Hmm, not sure why you need JSON_PATH_EXISTS at all? Since you anyway test for non-null values later? The point of linked question was he wanted to see if value was null but still existed in the json

@siggemannen maybe you are right, I just copied an example for testing purposes, don't wanna stick to just server2022, but very nice remark

Try removing JSON_PATH_EXISTS parts from your sql server 2022 version code and see if it works for you.

@siggemannen yep, that works the same. Is it compatible with older versions then?

The incompatibility was when you called JSON_PATH_EXISTS. I think you can answer your own question

Looks like you want aggregation over the whole OPENJSON set. You can use conditional aggregation in a HAVING for this.
SELECT
  l.* 
FROM Logs l
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
   FROM OPENJSON(l.Parameters) j
   HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN j.[key] = 'Name' AND j.value = 'Test'                                 THEN 1 END) > 0
      AND COUNT(CASE WHEN j.[key] = 'Guid' AND j.value = '37aaecc3-e2f9-4b39-afcf-ba720c4e500a' THEN 1 END) > 0
);

A better idea might be to use OPENJSON with a schema, then you only get one row for the whole object, with actual properties as columns broken out.
SELECT
  l.* 
FROM Logs l
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
   FROM OPENJSON(l.Parameters)
     WITH (
        Name nvarchar(100),
        Guid uniqueidentifier
     ) j
    WHERE j.Name = 'Test'
      AND j.Guid = '37aaecc3-e2f9-4b39-afcf-ba720c4e500a'
);


The following statement provides an option to query the stored JSON for multiple keys including possible NULL values.
SELECT * 
FROM [Logs]
WHERE EXISTS (  
   SELECT 1
   FROM OPENJSON(Parameters)
   WHERE 
      ([key] = 'Name' AND [value] = 'Test') OR
      ([key] = 'Guid' AND [value] = '37aaecc3-e2f9-4b39-afcf-ba720c4e500a')
      -- or possible NULL values
      --([key] = 'Guid' AND [value] IS NULL)
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [key]) = 2
)

